# How can I retrieve number of records in queue with SalesForce push topic

Tags: salesforce

How can I retrieve number of records in queue with SalesForce push topic?
I want to be notify for every change in the queue, one of those changes is new records in the queue, is there any way to do that?
count() can't be use in push topics

Thanks 
Tzelon M

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a separate object, let's call it QueueSize. Each object type would have a single instance of a QueueSize record, which would contain a field for the size. You could then implement triggers that would increment/decrement the QueueSize's size field, and do a PushTopic on that object.

The caveat is that depending on the activity of your queue size's fluctuations, this might not scale well as the record would constantly be in contention for locking.